# Unity3D cross platform Augmented Reality Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Is there a AR plugin for Unity3d which can work on Android, Iphone, Mac and Windows etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but while last year no any plugin like that is exist, some of plugins worked on mobile devices some only on desktops.

By my opinion for mobile devices the best it's Vuforia plugin.
Officially Vuforia not supported desktops but I guess with some tricks is possible 
to start using it by that way (try to look this: [How to use vuforia on PC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838755/how-to-use-vuforia-on-pc-application)).

Other solution is to use OpenCV bindings inside unity.