# How to use vuforia on PC Application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

i'm new on vuforia and i need some help with this topic. 
Can someone tells me if its possible use vuforia with a webcam on a pc application? 
I got webcam frames on a plane texture and i tried to pass those textures to vuforia but i have not got it work.

I used `WebCamTexture` to get frames of webcam.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Vuforia (although it looks interesting, I'm going to try that out myself this weekend!), I might have a suggestion.

Is it possible Vuforia doesn't know what to do because of the images being `WebCamTexture` instead of something like `Texture2d`?

`WebCamTexture` is a `Texture` (`Texture2D`, `WebCamTexture`, `RenderTexture` all extend from `Texture` but they aren't exchangeable).

So, try to convert your texture and pass that on to Vuforia?

```
var tx2d = new Texture2D();
tx2d.SetPixels((go.renderer.material.mainTexture as WebCamTexture).GetPixels());
```

**EDIT:** What I found [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-2-compiling-simple-project), under the section `Running in the editor`:

There is a specific `Web Cam Behaviour` script.

> To use Play Mode for Vuforia in Unity Pro, simply select the attached,
>   or built-in, webcam that you want to use from the Camera Device menu,
>   and then activate Play Mode using the Play button at the top of the
>   Editor UI.
>
> You can also use the standard Unity Play Mode with non-Pro Unity
>   versions and by setting ‘Don’t use for Play Mode’ in the Web Cam
>   Behaviour component.
>
> To use standard Play Mode, adjust the transform of the ARCamera object
>   to get your entire scene in view, and then run the application in the
>   Unity editor. There is no live camera image or tracking in standard
>   Play Mode, instead all Targets are assumed to be visible. This allows
>   you to test the non-AR components of your application, such as scripts
>   and animations, without having to deploy to the device each time.

Comment: Vuforia uses WebCamTexture to get the web cam images. I use Web Cam Behaviour to use it in play mode and it works fine. But the problem is that i would use it in a PC deploy application ( standalone app in windows f.e.) . Do u Know if that its possible?

Comment: Are you saying it works when you run it in Play Mode, but doesn't work when you deploy the application and run the .exe?

Comment: Yes, the Web Cam Behaviour only works in Play Mode. I've tried to test it in a deploy application and i have got an error: DLLNotFoundException..., Off course first i've change some code parts to make it work, but finally no result

Comment: What is the full message? What DLL seems to be missing? I'll be able to look in  Unity itself in a few hours so I can test it myself.

Comment: It seems that only one dll is getting problem, QCARWrapper.dll. Console output only says DllNotFoundException. Probably QCARWrapper.dll needs some others that it would import itself. I don't Know. If you can test it, please let me know.

Comment: Isn't that DLL not somewhere in the asset files? You could copy the DLL manually to your folder. I'm guessing it has a location given with it? `/Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll`? Try and copy the DLL to your build folder.

Comment: I tried it but is still not working. I guess that Vuforia is not supported for standalone applications. Did u try it?

Comment: I haven't yet but I will get into it this weekend! I'll update here if I find something!

Comment: Anyone has more info on this yet?

Comment: @Toad I'm sorry but I haven't been able to spend time using Unity3d anymore due to circumstances. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @DavidPrieto it was few years ago and by that time i found vuforia doesn't support desktop deployment, only mobile. You can refer on this link to see why https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/general-discussion/vuforia-support-desktopstandalone-apps, whatever check it on the official portal or get in touch with someone on vuforia site. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the $250 plugin at http://holographi.space/ ? I haven't paid $250 for it yet.